# libGDX: Trying to implement AdMob but can't get it to work

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I've been busy going through a bunch of documentation and tutorials to figure out how to implement AdMob into my game, but no luck so far.

The LibGDX wiki documentation is a bit outdated and some of the code is simply not working [-> link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx)

f.e. initializeForView doesn't take in boolean values anymore , or the adView method can't be used like this anymore:

```
View gameView = initializeForView(new HelloWorld(this), false);
```

.... or

```
// Create and setup the AdMob view
```

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxx"); // Put in your secret key here
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

I also worked through the Google AdMob documentation [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start), but it isn't very good aplicable to a LibGDX project.
I even tried just getting it running with AndroidStudio without using libgdx, but even that I didn't get to work accordingly.

I tried to work around it, but after a full days of tryingI still haven't been able to get any test ads on my android device when debugging on my device & any help would be more than welcome.

Can someone help me with this?
Does anyone know some more up to date info on how to set up AdMob in your libgdx project?

---

Here's what my AndroidManifest.xml looks like: [url=http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?action=pastebin&hex=f9d35261d1111[/url]

And here's a version of my AndroidLauncher.java that I was hoping to show me some adds but it isn't:[url=http://www.java-gaming.org/?action=pastebin&id=1113[/url]

Comment: Where/When do you call the `showAds(boolean show)` method in the AndroidLauncher?

Comment: Good point. There are more issues with the code though.
I used Nana Ghartey's suggestions in the post below and that got it to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's the updated guide](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-(replaces-deprecated-AdMob)) on setting up both admob banner and interstitial ads in a libgdx game using the google play services.

A simpler way to keep the banner shown is to set its background.

```
adMobView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

You can modify your code as provided in the docs as follows:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
    cfg.useCompass = false;

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    AdView admobView = createAdView();
    layout.addView(admobView);
    View gameView = createGameView(cfg);
    layout.addView(gameView);

    setContentView(layout);
    startAdvertising(admobView);
  }

  private AdView createAdView() {
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.setId(12345); // this is an arbitrary id, allows for relative positioning in createGameView()
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    return adView;
  }

  private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new AdTutorial(), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
  }

  private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) adView.resume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

Comment: Yes! Got it to work finally. Thanks.
Small details though:
@ cfg.useGL20 = false;
AndroidApplicationConfiguration doesn't have a method useGL20 anymore
& 
AS reports an "expected resource of type id" error with:
adView.setId(12345);
The code runs though & I have to set the ID in order to have the ad banner shown

Comment: Yes! 12345 is just a dummy id. You should replace it with your admob adunit id. Please accept answer to help those with similar problems find it. Thanks

Comment: Took care of it.  I'm linking this post to the JGO forum, in case anyone having similar problems.
Thanks a bunch for taking the time to help out

Comment: Maybe u have some advice on integrating interstitial adds? (that's the type of adds i actually wanted and not the banner).
Implementing interstitial adds works slightly different & following the Libgdx documentation didnt get it to work because i keep getting problems with the ActionResolver that i can't seem to pass/use with my games main class... I'm probably gonna create a separate thread for that. Google's documentation is also no use. To different from a Libgdx project setup

Comment: Got Interstitial adds to work too. Not sure why I don't have any porblems with passing the ActionResolver anymore...

For anyone having problems as well with incorporating interstatials following this tutorial, some of the code is outdated:

- in your AndroidLauncher remove cfg.useGL20 (not being used anymore)
- change the texture that's being refered to in AdTutorial.java to: texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg")); ("newer" libgdx distribution use differnet filename+location)
- take a good look at filelocation of the tutorialfiles in the git repo

Answer (score 0):

You should check/post your logcat for any Admob related logs.

Anyway I've came across something like your problem some time ago and solved it by making the adView background transparent:

`adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Don't know the reason why it worked.